# How to display information from data table?

Tags: vb.net

I am developing app using vb.net, all the information recorded in ms access. Can anyone teach me how to fetch information from 1st and 2nd column of 1st row in data table to be display in textbox.

This is the code that i've tried and  of course it didn't work as i want it to be.

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Sum([SharkTWbySpecies]), Sum([RayTWbySpecies])  From TWbySpecies Where [OperationID] =" & TextBoxOpID4.Text, myConnection)
    Dim AllSampleTW As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    TextBoxAllSharkSampleTW.Text = AllSampleTW.ToString()
    TextBoxAllRaySampleTW.Text = AllSampleTW.ToString()
```

Hoping that someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) to fetch the data.FYI, Use parameterized query to avoid [`sql injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Sum([SharkTWbySpecies]), Sum([RayTWbySpecies])  From TWbySpecies Where [OperationID] =@val", myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", TextBoxOpID4.Text)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read ' loop through the datareader and get values of each column  
                TextBoxAllSharkSampleTW.Text = dr(0)
                TextBoxAllRaySampleTW.Text = dr(1)
            End While
        End If
```